# Trying to make a reliable UDP but my code does not work, I can not know exactly why but I think it is due to select, FD_ISSET or recvfrom

Tags: c, tcp, udp

I trying to code reliable UDP protocol. I use linux like OS and VS code like IDE. I started with threeway handshake but has got stuck. I load all my code so you can see it. Like you see I have many printf with number and its just for debug. When I run the server from the terminal I get 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12 and after that nothing happen. In the same time when I start the client I get i 1, 2, 3 and Timeout like a output. I think the select in server after `printf("12")` Don't work and same for `FD_ISSET` and `recvfrom`.  Maybe I should also point out that sendto() in server have a yellow dash under `fileDescriptor` and when I click on it the program show me `int *fileDescriptor passing argument 1 of ‘sendto’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

Packet.h

```
#ifndef PACKET_H  
#define PACKET_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define PORT 5555
#define MAXMSG 4096
#define MAX_DATA 50

typedef struct rtp_struct{

bool ACK, FIN, RES, SYN;
size_t ACK_Number, Flags, ID, SEQ, Window_Size, CRC; 
unsigned short CheckSum, Length;
char Data[MAX_DATA];

} RTP;

void Set_Default_Values(RTP *rtp);
void SEQ_Generator (RTP *rpt);
short CheckSum_Function (char *buffer, int length);

#endif
```

Packet.c

```
#include "Packet.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Set_Default_Values(RTP *rtp){ 

rtp->ACK = false;
rtp->SYN = false;
rtp->FIN = false;
rtp->RES = false;

rtp->ACK_Number = 0;
rtp->CheckSum = 0;
rtp->Length = 0;
rtp->Data[0] = '\0';
}

void SEQ_Generator (RTP *rpt){ 

size_t result = 0, High = 0, Low = 0, Min = 1, Max = 4294967294;

if(Min < Max){
    Low = Min;
    High = Max + 1;
}
else {
    Low = Max + 1;
    High = Min;
}

result = rand() % (High - Low) + Low;

rpt->SEQ = result;
}

short CheckSum_Function (char *buffer, int length){

int SumOfACSII = 0;
int i = 0;

while(buffer[i] != '\0'){
    SumOfACSII += buffer[i];
    i++;
}
return SumOfACSII;
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "Packet.h"

#define PORT 5555
#define hostNameLength 50
#define messageLength  256

pthread_t rThread;



void Init_Socket_Address(struct sockaddr_in *name, char *hostName, unsigned short int port) {

  struct hostent *hostInfo; 

  name->sin_family = AF_INET;
  name->sin_port = htons(port);
  hostInfo = gethostbyname(hostName);

  if(hostInfo == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Init socket address - Unknown host %s\n",hostName);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  name->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)hostInfo->h_addr;
}

int Client_Threeway_Handshake (int fileDescriptor, fd_set *activeFdSet, struct sockaddr_in *Server_Name){

    short int condition = 0;
    short int counter = 3;
    short int Window_Size = rand() % 10 + 3;
    short int nOfBytes = 0;
    bool run = 1;
    size_t ACK_ID = 0;

    fd_set readFdSet;
    RTP Send_SYN;
    RTP Send_ACK;
    RTP Received_ACK;
    struct timeval timer;

    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    while (run){
        
        switch (condition){

        case 0: // Sending SYN and receiving ACK + SYN
            
            Set_Default_Values(&Send_SYN);
            Send_SYN.SYN = true;
            Send_SYN.Length = Window_Size;
            SEQ_Generator(&Send_SYN);

            while(counter > 0 && condition == 0){

                nOfBytes = sendto(fileDescriptor, &Send_SYN, sizeof(Send_SYN), 0, (struct sockaddr*)Server_Name, sizeof(*Server_Name));
                printf("Client: send SYN with SEQ!\n");
                printf("1\n");
                timer.tv_sec = 2;
                timer.tv_usec = 0;
                printf("2\n");
                readFdSet = *activeFdSet;

                if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, &timer) == -1){
                    printf("Client: select failed!\n");
                }
                printf("3\n");
                if(FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor, &readFdSet)){
                    printf("4\n");
                    if(recvfrom(fileDescriptor, &Received_ACK, MAXMSG, 0, (struct sockaddr*)Server_Name, &len) == 0){
                        printf("5\n");
                        if(Received_ACK.ACK == true && Received_ACK.SYN == true && Received_ACK.ACK_Number == Send_SYN.SEQ){
                            printf("Client: recevied ACK + SYN!\n");
                            ACK_ID = Received_ACK.SEQ;
                            Window_Size = Received_ACK.Length;
                            condition = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            printf("Client: Don't recevied ACK + SYN!\n");
                        }
                    }

                }
                else{
                    printf("--- Timeout ---\n");
                    counter--;
                    condition = 0;
                    if(counter == 0){ exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
                }

            }

            break;
        case 1: // Sending ACK on ACK + SYN

            Set_Default_Values(&Send_ACK);
            SEQ_Generator(&Send_ACK);

            Send_ACK.ACK = true;
            Send_ACK.ACK_Number = ACK_ID;

            do{
                printf("Client: Send ACK with SEQ\n");
                sendto(fileDescriptor, &Send_ACK, sizeof(Send_ACK), 0, (struct sockaddr*)Server_Name, sizeof(*Server_Name));

                struct timeval timer;
                timer.tv_sec = 2;
                timer.tv_usec = 0;
                readFdSet = *activeFdSet;

                if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, &timer) == -1){
                    printf("Client: select failed!\n");
                }

                if(FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor, &readFdSet)){
                    RTP Received_ACK_2;
                    recvfrom(fileDescriptor, &Received_ACK_2, MAXMSG, 0, (struct sockaddr*)Server_Name, sizeof(*Server_Name));

                    if(Received_ACK_2.ACK == true && Received_ACK_2.SYN == true && Received_ACK_2.ACK_Number == Send_SYN.SEQ){
                        printf("Client: recevied duplicate of ACK + SYN!\n");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    run = 0;
                    printf("--- Client: Three-way handshake successful --- \n");
                }
            }
            while (run == 1);
            
            
            break;

        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serverName;
    char hostName[hostNameLength];
    char messageString[messageLength];
    fd_set activeFdSet;

    if(argv[1] == NULL) {
        perror("Usage: client [host name]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        strncpy(hostName, argv[1], hostNameLength);
        hostName[hostNameLength - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Host is : %s\n",hostName);
    }

    /* Create the socket */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if(sock < 0) {
    perror("Could not create a socket\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Init_Socket_Address(&serverName, hostName, PORT);
    FD_ZERO(&activeFdSet);
    FD_SET(sock, &activeFdSet);

    printf("3: %d\n", sock);

    Client_Threeway_Handshake(sock, &activeFdSet, &serverName);

    printf("---Connected----");
}
```

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "Packet.h"

#define PORT 5555
#define MAXMSG 512

pthread_t rThread;
size_t LastReceviedSEQ;

int Make_Socket(unsigned short int port){

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in name;

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (sock < 0){
        perror("Could not create a socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_port = htons(port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&name, sizeof(name)) < 0){
        perror("Could not bind a name to the socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (sock);
}

int Server_ThreeWay_Handshake(int fileDescriptor, fd_set *activFdSet, struct sockaddr_in *client){
    printf("10\n");
    short int condition = 0;
    short int run = 0;
    short int i = 0;
    short int Window_Size = rand() % 10 + 3;

    fd_set readFdSet;
    RTP Read;
    RTP Write;
    struct timeval timer;
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    
    printf("11\n");
    do{
        switch (condition){

        case 0:
            readFdSet = *activFdSet;
            printf("12\n");

            if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0){
                printf("Server: select fail!\n");
            }
            printf("15\n");
            if(FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor, &readFdSet)){
                printf("13\n");
                if(recvfrom(fileDescriptor, &Read, MAXMSG, 0, (struct sockaddr*)client, &len) == 0){
                    printf("14\n");
                    if(Read.SYN == true){
                        printf("Server: revevied SYN from client!\n");

                        if(Read.Length < Window_Size){
                            Window_Size = Read.Length;
                        }
                        condition = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        
        case 1:
            Set_Default_Values(&Write);
            Write.ACK = true;
            Write.SYN = true;
            Write.Length = Window_Size;

            SEQ_Generator(&Write);
            Write.ACK_Number = Read.SEQ;

            do{
                sendto(fileDescriptor, &Write, sizeof(Write), 0, (struct sockaddr*)client, sizeof(*client));
                printf("Server: send ACK + SYN!\n");
                timer.tv_sec = 0;
                timer.tv_usec = 500000;
                readFdSet = *activFdSet;

                if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, &timer) == -1){
                    printf("Server: select failed!\n");
                }

                if(FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor, &readFdSet)){

                    if(recvfrom(fileDescriptor, &Read, MAXMSG, 0, (struct sockaddr*)client, sizeof(*client)) == 0){
                        Set_Default_Values(&Read);
                    }
                    if(Read.ACK == true && Read.ACK_Number == Write.SEQ){
                            printf("Server: recevied ACK from client!\n");
                            condition = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Server: Don't recevied ACK from client!\n");
                        i++;
                    }

                }
                else{
                    printf("--- Timeout ---\n");
                }
                 if(i == 0){ exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
            
            }while(condition == 1 && i <= 3);

            break;

            case 2:
                LastReceviedSEQ = Read.SEQ;
                printf("--- Server: Three-way handshake successful --- \n");
                break;

        }
    }while(run == 1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sock;
    fd_set activeFdSet, readFdSet;
    struct sockaddr_in clientName;
    printf("1\n");
    /* Create a socket and set it up to accept connections */
    sock = Make_Socket(PORT);
    FD_ZERO(&activeFdSet);
    FD_SET(sock, &activeFdSet);
    printf("2\n");
    printf("\n[waiting for connections...]\n");
    printf("3\n");
    Server_ThreeWay_Handshake(sock, &activeFdSet, &clientName);
    printf("4\n");
}
```

Comment: If the function wants to have an `int` you must not pass an `int*`. Why does function `Server_ThreeWay_Handshake` need a pointer to the file descriptor instead of the file descriptor itself? Compare with function `Write_Message`. There you use `int fileDescriptor` as the argument for `sendto`. Please [edit] your question if you want to to add information or clarification.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you I fix it but it still not working I get same output.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and fix all warnings. There are still warnings about wrong data types. Check the return value of all functions for errors and handle the errors.

Comment: @Bodo I think its done now, I get same output for client but for server i get 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15, 13, 4. So the recvfrom don't work.

Comment: I still get warnings about wrong data types. Please show the compile commands in your question. If you use GCC I suggest to use options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes`